# GtkMessageDialog delay on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome

Initially when an application opens a `GtkMessageDialog` on my Ubuntu 19.10 system there is a delay of about 1-2 seconds for which the application freezes, before showing the dialog and playing the dialog sound. Following dialogs open immediately in the same application, however after a brief time period of not opening a dialog, the first dialog is delayed again.

I reckon this has to do something with the sound, since dialogs with message type `GTK_MESSAGE_OTHER`, which don't play a sound, are never delayed.

What could be causing this?

I have the latest updates installed:

```
GNOME Shell 3.34.1
Gtk 3.24.12-1ubuntu1
```

**Edit**: I have noticed the same behavior with the terminal bell, so I am starting to think this is a general issue with system sounds. I have a suspicion this is caused by parts of gnome being installed through `snap`, which has caused downright unacceptable performance for the calculator app as well on my computer.

However I still do not know how I could fix this

Comment: If this is a Gtk GUI programming question it belongs on Stack Overflow

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix No this is not a programming question, the issue occurs with every application using the standard dialogs like LibreOffice or Nautilus.